# Question about integral containing derivative of Dirac delta distribution

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, dirac-delta-distributions, variational-calculus

[image]

The result of the integral of the dirac delta δ(x-a) times a function f should be f(a) right? Then why isn't the integral just the final result directly without doing all of this, where did the highlighted term come from and why is there a negative sign before the second term?

Comment: Your limits are $t_i,\,t_f$, but you're reasoning as if they're $-\infty,\,\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts of the 2nd term, that has the time derivative of the Dirac delta distribution.

You needed to do this because you have not yet learnt how to deal with derivatives of the Dirac delta distribution. If you did, you would not have asked this question and made this mistake. That is why the text is being pedagogical and nice and slow.

You really need to write a better title, so that people can search for this, if they run into the same problem as you did.